# what is the "as" keyword in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am quite new to Swift and iOS.

I am just reading some sample codes. There is a line I cannot understand:

```
let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
```

What does "as" do here?

Thanks

Comment: It's a forced downcast.  See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question.

Comment: @user623396: One reason for a downvote is "the question does not show any research effort". The `as` keyword is **documented**
 in the official Swift documentation (https://itunes.apple.com/de/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?l=en&mt=11). So one can expect that OP has read the docs, and explains what exactly is not understood. Otherwise the question is too broad and/or unclear.

Comment: @user623396 I didn't downvote, but this question doesn't demonstrate having done any research. I might have cut him a little slack (as searching for a common word like "as" would often generate a lot of false positives), but if one was diligent, a review of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) would have answered the question. Jumping to the "summary of the grammar" section of the "reference" chapter can be useful in getting clues about the syntax.

Comment: Many thanks guys, but i have spent a lot of times on searching it from the document. So i guess it's easier to get some help from the community. Anyways, thanks for the help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use the `as` keyword to cast data types. [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) `rootViewController` is of type `UIViewController`. You downcast it to `UISplitViewController`.